# Proving that $[E(a):F(a)] \leq [E:F]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

We're trying to prove that for a tower of fields $K/E/F$, if $a$ is algebraic over $F$ then $[E(a):F(a)] \leq [E:F]$. This is what I have so far,

$\textbf{Proof:}$                              Suppose for a contradiction that $[E(\alpha)  : F(\alpha)] > [E : F]$. First, we claim that  $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$, it must be algebraic over
$E$. Indeed, any polynomial $f \in F[x]$ such that  $f(\alpha) = 0$ is contained in $E[x]$. Next, we claim that  $[F(a) : E] \leq [E(\alpha) : E]$.
Indeed, let $m(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ in  $E[x]$ and  $f$ be the minimal polynomial of  $\alpha$ in $F[x]$. Then $f(x) \in
        E[x]$ and hence $m(x)  \mid f(x)$. Hence $\deg f(x) \geq  \deg m(x)$ so that $[F(\alpha) : F] \geq  [E(\alpha) : E]$. We proceed with a case analysis.
If $[F(\alpha) : F] = [E(\alpha) : E]$ then by our hypothesis and the tower theorem we would have that
$$
           [E(\alpha) : F] =  [E(\alpha)  : F(\alpha)] [F(\alpha) : F] > [E(\alpha) : E][E: F] = [E(\alpha) : F]
        ,$$
a contradiction. If $[F(\alpha) : F] > [E(\alpha) : E]$, then again by our hypothesis and the tower theorem we would have that
$$
           [E(\alpha) : F] =  [E(\alpha)  : F(\alpha)] [F(\alpha) : F] > [E(\alpha) : E][E: F] = [E(\alpha) : F]
        ,$$
a contradiction. We conclude that $[E(\alpha)  : F(\alpha)] \leq [E : F]$

I was wondering if someone can check the proof for correctness?

Comment: Looks correct. Why is there a field $K$ in the statement though?

Comment: Well that’s why I was hesitant. I never used it in my proof!

Comment: I added the appropriate tag (solution verification). According to [its description](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info), "This tag should be used when you have a proposed solution to a problem and you have specific concerns or doubts about the validity of that solution. A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough." This site is not meant as a proof-checking machine.

Comment: Okay. Sorry I'm new to this website. What websites are more catered towards proof-checking/assistance?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, I think it is correct! I cannot find any mistakes.

Comment: Thanks. I was hesitant because I never used the larger field $K$.